# Navigation Controller inside UIView

Tags: iphone, ios4

Whe I create a new UIViewController and try to put inside a NavigationController in the usual way (drag-drop in the xib and create the outlet), I show the Navigationcontroller with:

```
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view]
```

The result is a Navigation Bar with a little band in the upper part (seems displaced down), (i can't post the image now but is like 20px empty space)

I tried to put the navigation controller on the top window:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

And it worked, but I'm unable to come back the initial screen whe I execute:

```
[navigationController.view removeFromSuperview]
```

or

```
[self dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It is possible to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationController* nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];
nav.navigationBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
NSLog(@"desc=%@",[nav.navigationBar description]);
[self.view addSubview:nav.navigationBar];
```

Try with above code. it will hide unnecessary space.
Thanks

Comment: Does not work... I think thre is something wrong with the UIView where I add the subview. Still testing.

Comment: Please check you have add [self.view addSubview:nav.navigationBar]; not its view.it's work at my side.

Comment: The problem was on the xib of the UIView where I put the navigation bar. Modifyint it to be bigger it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

20 pixels sounds like the status bar. Make sure in your nib that the status bar option for the view is set to None. Hope that Helps!